# Java Runnable doesn't work

Tags: java, swing

I got a class that loads news.

```
package swing;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;
import net.Logger;
import net.Util;

public class WebPanel extends JScrollPane implements Runnable {
    private JTextPane editorPane;
    private String link;

    public WebPanel(final String link) {
        this.link = link;
        editorPane = new JTextPane();
        editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
        editorPane.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        editorPane.setEditable(false);
        editorPane.setMargin(null);
        editorPane.setBorder(null);
        setBorder(null);
        editorPane.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        editorPane.setText("<html><body><font color=\"#808080\"><br><center>Getting data</center></font></body></html>");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            editorPane.setPage(new URL(link));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.logError("setting web page failed ", e);
            editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
            editorPane.setText("<html><body><font color=\"#808080\"><br><center>Failed to get data<br>" + e.toString() + "</center></font></body></html>");
        }

        editorPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent he) {
                if (he.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                    try {
                        Util.openLink(he.getURL().toURI());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Logger.logError("hyperlinkUpdate failed", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }); 

        setViewportView(editorPane);
   }

   public String GetLink() {
       return editorPane.getPage().toString();
   }
   public final void setLink(final String link) {
       this.link = link;
   }}
```

It is runnable, but when I update page (I've got GUI class where I do that) Lo

```
public static WebPanel scrollPane = new WebPanel(Util.newslink);
...
LoginForm.scrollPane.setLink(Util.newslink);
new Thread(LoginForm.scrollPane).start();
```

My program doesn't work (no buttons can be pressed) until it loads a page. I tried creating Threads using `invokeLater()`, but nothing helped.

Comment: You are interacting with GUI objects from a thread which is not the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) - that is generally a bad idea...

Comment: Can you remove the bits of code that aren't necessary to reproduce the unwanted behaviour?

Comment: This is a massive violation of the swing thread rules of Swing, your starting a second thread which is interacting with the UI components which is wrong. You should be using a SwingWorker to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that you are waiting the web download in your GUI thread. Doing so blocks the GUI while you wait.

If you don't want this to happen use another thread for the download and use invokeLater to take the result and update the GUI when it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are making blocking call on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) which is responsible for updating the GUI.  This will give the appears that the app is not doing anything because it's unable to update until your blocking call.  You should really make use of a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to do the "heavy" work on a background Thread.

Take a look at the tutorial [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for a detailed more detail on how to execute long running tasks on a background thread.